# Cant call .ajax inside autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have been trying for days to get the jQuery autocomplete to work. Right now I have it to the point that I can type in the textbox and it shows me exactly what I want, but my problem is that I when I click on the one that I want, it does not show up in the textbox. I know it has something to do with the autocomplete but I can not figure it out for the life of me. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

index.php

```
<?php require('_php/functions.php') ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head>
  <title>simple_light</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="_style/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
            <h1> Autocomplete with jQuery</h1>
            <input type="text" name="autosuggest" id="autosuggest" onKeyUp="autoSuggest();"/>
            <div id="autosuggest-container"></div>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
            <script src="_scripts/functions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

functions.js

```
function autoSuggest(){

var autosuggestVal = $('#autosuggest').val();

    if (autosuggestVal != ''){
        $.ajax({
            url: '_php/ajax/autosuggest.php?query='+autosuggestVal,
            success: function(result){
                $('#autosuggest-container').html(result);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

functions.php

```
<?php 
require('config.php');

function autoSuggest($query){

    $connect = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connect);

    $sql = "
    SELECT Location.LocationID, CONCAT_WS(' ', SystemName, SiteNameLocation, SiteAddress1, SiteCity, SiteProvince, SitePostalCode) as expr2 
    FROM Location 
    WHERE Location.SystemName like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($query)."%'
    OR Location.SiteNameLocation like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($query)."%'
    OR Location.SiteAddress1 like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($query)."%'
    OR Location.SiteCity like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($query)."%'
    OR Location.SiteProvince like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($query)."%'
    OR Location.SitePostalCode like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($query)."%'
    ";

    $result = mysql_query($sql, $connect);
    $totalRows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($totalRows > 0){
        $items = '<ul class="autosuggest">';

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

            $items .= '<li>'.$row['expr2'].'</li>';

        }

        $items .= '</ul>';

    }
    else{
        $items = 'no results found';
    }

    echo $items;

}
?>
```

autosuggest.php

```
<?php 
require('../functions.php');
autoSuggest($_GET['query']);
?>
```

Comment: If you provide a JSFiddle with mock data this will get solved very quickly :)

Answer (score 0):

It is my strong suspicion you're not providing a click event handler on the suggestions - how does it know how to set the value if you don't tell it how to?

See this rough example (I mocked out the ajax call to a simple "hello" response every time)

http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/X2K4K/2/

I wire up the two events in the JS rather than on the objects - much easier and nicer.

```
$('#autosuggest').on('keyup', autoSuggest);
$('#autosuggest-container').on('click', setValue)
```

As you can see, the keyup event is bound to the autosuggest id and the onclick event is bound to the autosuggest-container.

On click for the autosuggest-container (aka the item you want to select) it then sets the value.

**Note:** in your example you'll probably need to pass the item you're interested in to the setValue function. YMMV

Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont think you understand...I want it to autofill the text box

Comment: If you click the option (in the fiddle) that shows up you'll notice it autofills the text box...